# Concurrency : full collection or element

Tags: java, concurrency

I have collections that i need update every single second. I use for that ScheduledExecutorService. But i have question, do it's better give thread pool full collection  or send each element of collection to thread pool?

Comment: It would depend on the task at hand. If you give more details of your problem, you'll get a more accurate answer.

Comment: The typical pattern is to provide all threads with reference to a collection, but as Luiggi wrote above, some details are neccesary to provide more argumented statements and recommendations.

Comment: @alexey-malev Can we speak private(skype/vk/email)? For me will be better speak on our native lang.

Comment: @eNsirius we can, but I think no later than tomorrow evening since I'm travelling. You can find me by name in vk and PM. But, after that, the solution needs to be posted there anyway.

Comment: Ok..but..can't find you. add me https://vk.com/ensirius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following solution:

- For `Map` collections, replace them with `ConcurrentHashMap`. This `map` has iterators tolerant to collection changes, and locking of it is striped based on keys `hashCode()`.
- For `Set` collections, use sets created by factory `Collections.newSetFromMap()` with `ConcurrentHashMap` instance passed as an argument. This will provide you with `set` with same thread-safety-related properties as for `map` I mentioned above.
- For `List` collections, first consider whether you really need `List`. If yes, consider using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or wrapping original list with

  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()); //or maybe LinkedList, but this is not related to the question.

Please be advised that iterators returned by this wrapped list are not thread-safe and may throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Now, you may encounter problem - `Set` returned by the factory, cannot have same values in it. If this is a problem for you, try use some Guava `Multiset`. Further information about it can be found [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html).

Ok, we finished with the collections. Now, let's consider its updates on the example of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Implementation of this structure provides you so-called eventual visibility guarantees. That means that each iterator represents some collection state - maybe not the last one, but the state **is guaranteed to be valid** at some moment of time, maybe in the past. Usually that is enough for most cases.

That means that to parallelize handling of some activities, you can pass the reference to this collection to your `Thread` or `Runnable` which modifies it, and to some other `Thread` or `Runnable` that reads it, and you should be fine.

Note that throughput for the `List` I mentioned above will be lower, because this collection is exclusively accessed due to `synchronized` blocks added by that wrapper.